# Disable "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" from the database for specific attribute

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, search

I've got a script that is extracting attributes and inserting them into my Magento installation. The problem is that one of the attributes has created hundreds of duplicate options.

If I set the option `Use In Search Results Layered Navigation` to `NO` and hit save, it complains that the `admin` value needs to be filled in. There are hundreds.

I want to disable this directly from the database so it doesnt show in the frontend and allow me to troubleshoot why this happened.

How do you disable layered navigation for a specific attribute from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this field `is_filterable_in_search` in table `catalog_eav_attribute` for your attribute.

This SQL query should do the job:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute`AS `cea`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `ea`
ON `ea`.`attribute_id` = `cea`.`attribute_id`
SET `cea`.`is_filterable_in_search` = 0
WHERE `ea`.`attribute_code` = 'MY_ATTRIBUTE'
```

Hope this help,

Comment: I didn't run the SQL query but just set `is_filterable_in_search` to `0` and it worked, thank you!